# STRCAT changes two variables at the same time

Tags: c++

I have a piece of code that is malfunctioning and I have no idea how it is doing what it is doing.

what I want to do is:

1. Have a function that receives a directory name `path` and a file name `filename`
2. Copy these 2 to another variable `caminho`
3. Copy the file from the current directory to the one received.

My function with my troubled code is:

```
void fileTransfer(const char* filename, const char* path, bool ts)
{
  std::cout << filename << std::endl;
  char *caminho;
  caminho[0] = '\0';
  std::cout << "0 " << caminho << ' ' << filename <<  std::endl;
  strcat(caminho, path);
  std::cout << "1 " << caminho << ' ' << filename << std::endl;
  strcat(caminho, "\\");
  std::cout << "2 " << caminho << ' ' << filename << std::endl;
  strcat(caminho, filename);
  std::cout << "3 " << caminho << ' ' << filename << std::endl;

  //does the rest
}
```

What this code should do is print simething like this:

```
file.txt
0 file.txt
C:\Users\Username file.txt
C:\Users\Username\ file.txt
C:\Users\Username\file.txt file.txt
```

However this code actually prints is this:

```
file.txt
0 
C:\Users\Username C:\Users\Username
C:\Users\Username\ C:\Users\Username\
C:\Users\Username\C:\Users\Username\C C:\Users\Username\C:\Users\Username\C
```

Also before all of this `strcat` I've printed `filename` and it's correct. Can anyone see whats wrong with this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not allocate memory where you are going to copy path and filename. You only defined a pointer that moreover was not initiazlied.

The correct function could look like

```
void fileTransfer( const char* filename, const char* path, bool ts )
{
    size_t n = strlen( path ) + strlen( filename ) + sizeof( "\\" );

    // char *caminho = malloc( n * sizeof( char ) ); for C or
    char *caminho = new char[ n ];

    caminho[0] = '\0';

    strcat( caminho, path );
    strcat( caminho, "\\" );
    strcat( caminho, filename );

    //does the rest
}
```

Also do not forget to free the allocated memory when the combined string will not be needed any more:

```
free( caminho ); // for C
delete [] caminho; // for C++
```

Take into account that as you are using C++ you could use class std::string.

For example

```
std::string caminho( path );

caminho += "\\";

caminho += filename;
```

and if you need to get a string you can use member function `c_str` . For example

```
caminho.c_str()
```

Comment: Hmm I tried doing this, but I did it wrong. Didn't use the `size_t` (haven't coded with C/C++ in a while). And won't I need to clear the memory allocatied by `malloc` in the end of the function?

Comment: @Comum I showed how the correct function could look. That is it is correct code that does not require any addition.

Comment: Yeah, it looks as it should do the trick. I'm implementing it to see if I get the proper results. Cheers!!!

Answer (score 4):

`caminho` doesn't point anywhere. You're overwriting random memory.

Why do you even use C string manipulation? Use `std::string`.

Comment: I am also working with `LCPCTSTR` / `LCPCWSTR` and I when I try to convert `std::string` to their type I get bad results, but with `char *` it works fine. 

But then how is `filename` updated as well? And, most important, why?

Comment: So use `std::wstring` for `LPCWSTR` and `std::basic_string<TCHAR>` for `LPCTSTR`. As it is, you have *undefined behavior* and thus your program can do whatever it wants. If you really insist on using C string manipulation, learn how to do it correctly. http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson9.html

Comment: Yeah, thats the info I was lacking. Cheers.